# How to use values from DOM in cypress test?

Tags: cypress

if I have a page containing:

```
  <span data-testid="credit-balance">
    10
  </span>
```

In Cypress, how do I extract the value to a variable to use in tests?

Something along the lines of:

```
const creditBalance = cy.get('[data-testid="credit-balance"]').value();
```

Comment: If you would like to test/assert the value of an input element, just use `.should('have.value', 'input value you test for')`. See [official docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Value) for more.

Answer (score 31):

Assigning return values with `const`, `var`, and `let` is considered an anti pattern while using Cypress. 
However, when you find yourself wanting to do so, is best practice to accomplish this with closures.

```
it("uses closures to reference dom element", () => {

   cy.get("[data-testid=credit-balance]").then(($span) => {

   // $span is the object that the previous command yielded

   const creditBalance = $span.text();

   cy.log(creditBalance);

  })

});
```

Another way to do this would be to use Aliases if you want to store and compare values or share values between tests using hooks.

```
it("aliasing the value from dom element", () => {

  cy.get("[data-testid=credit-balance]").as("creditBalance")

  cy.get("@creditBalance").should("contain", 10)

});
```

How you approach this really depends on the objective of your test. I recommend checking out more examples from the documentation: try [Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#) , [Best Practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#content-inner), and [FAQ](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html)

Comment: since saving values is considered anti-pattern, how would one compare a previous app state value with a future state value?

Comment: I'm also looking for that. I need to store class atribute value of DOM element in some place and then after performing some actions compare it with the current state.

Comment: How would you use 'creditBalance' outside that scope, after the callback? I need to use it to compare it later on another steps. Should I make all the logic inside then()? I don't seem to be able to make flow awaits for it..

Comment: how do you take the value of const creditBalance to another spec file that will run after this one ? a global variable..use window keyword ?

Answer (score 4):

The Cypress documentation has an example how to [Compare text values of two elements](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Compare-text-values-of-two-elements)

```
// will keep text from title element
let titleText

cy.get('.company-details')
  .find('.title')
  .then(($title) => {
    // save text from the first element
    titleText = $title.text(); //original uses normalizeText($title.text())
  })

cy.get('.company-details')
  .find('.identifier')
  .should(($identifier) => {
    // we can massage text before comparing
    const idText = $identifier.text(); //original uses normalizeText($identifier.text())

    // text from the title element should already be set
    expect(idText, 'ID').to.equal(titleText)
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to retrieve the value and perform any assertions with it, a fast, efficient method would also be the use `.invoke`

```
it('Getting the value and performing an assertion', () =>{
   cy.get('selector').invoke('val').should('eq',10) 
})
```

[Doc](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html#Syntax)

Answer (score 1):

> If you have to get the value rather than text, use this. It worked for me.

```
<span data-testid="credit-balance" value='100'></span>
```

> Like above

```
cy.get('[data-testid="credit-balance"]')
    .invoke("val")
    .then(($amount) => {
      // $span is the object that the previous command yielded

      cy.log($amount);
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use prop() from JQuery and assign it to const value

```
const value = cy.get('[data-testid="credit-balance"]').prop('name of the property');
```

prop() will return you property value as string