# How to get div 'text' value in Cypress test using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

Using Jquery in Cypress.io test, how to get the div 'text' value called 'Wildness' from the below html tag. I have tried below in my Cypress test, but it is throwing undefined in console.

```
const $divText = Cypress.$('.ibxudA .WildnessText-kRKTej').text()
         cy.wrap($divText)
           .should("eq", "Wildness")
```

```html
<div class="sc-bMvGRv_onetwo">
<div>
<div class="abLeftSection">
<div class="abNewBtn-fTLJBK">
<button class="ifAKCX ohpWT" type="button">New</button>
</div>
<div class="kpLvEV" style="">
<div class="cWzXYZ">
<div class="OgGUG">
<div class="jsnnAD">
<svg class="dFvKsA"></svg>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ibxudA">First</div>
</div>
<div class="kpLvEV" style="">
<div class="bGADLM"><div class="OgGUG">
<div class="jsnnAD">
<svg class="dFvKsA"></svg>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ibxudA">
<div class="WildnessText-kRKTej" title="Wildness">Wildness</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use values from DOM in cypress test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730959/how-to-use-values-from-dom-in-cypress-test)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I might try this:

```
cy.get(".ibxudA").find('.WildnessText-kRKTej').should('have.text',"Wildness")
```

**or**

```
cy.get(".ibxudA").find('.WildnessText-kRKTej').invoke('text').then((text) => {
    expect(text.trim()).equal('Wildness')
});
```

This might be a similar question: [How do you check the equality of the inner text of a element using cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52430983/how-do-you-check-the-equality-of-the-inner-text-of-a-element-using-cypress)

Comment: I took your HTML and tested it using cypress and the above did work. Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 20):

```
cy.get("WildnessText-kRKTej").then(function($elem) {
     cy.log($elem.text())
})
```

Comment: This is an absolute beauty

Answer (score 10):

One line validation:

Syntax:

```
cy.get(<selector>).invoke("text").should("eq", <your string>);
```

Example:

```
cy.get("div.myclass").invoke("text").should("eq", "My Text");
```

Here, following method is used for retrieving text. `should()` is used for validation.

```
cy.get('element').invoke('text')
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
    it('get text', async () => {
      const text = await new Cypress.Promise<string>((resolve) => {
        cy.get('[data-testid="target"')
          .invoke('text')
          .then((txt) => resolve(txt.toString()))
      })

      cy.log(text)
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you use inbuilt cypress API 'contains' like this:

```
cy.contains('Wildness')
```

It will select the whole HTML tag for you. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 3):

As of July 2020, from Cypress docs (https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-get-an-element%E2%80%99s-text-contents):

```
cy.get('div').should(($div) => {
  const text = $div.text()

  expect(text).to.match(/foo/)
  expect(text).to.include('foo')
  expect(text).not.to.include('bar')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.get('.ibxudA .WildnessText-kRKTej').invoke('text').then((yourDivText) => {
   expect(yourDivText.toString().toLowerCase()).to.contain('wildness');
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, but it Failed to find the element CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '.ibxudA .WildnessText-kRKTej', but never found it.

Comment: It is just the selector. You can refactor this value as you need.

Comment: you could try just ".WildnessText-kRKTej" since your class is unique.