# How to take value from the element in the Cypress tool?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I have a problem with taking value of the element like:

```
<div class="Test">Number 10</div>
```

Let say, that I have 10-20 classes with values like here, then I can use:

```
cy.get('.Test').invoke('text').as.('Field1')
```

to get proper value, but it is only possible in different test by using this.Field1. 
How to get value in the same test without using: 
**then and .text()**?

Is it possible? I have many fields and I would like do it in one single test to check proper values in the next view.

Did anyone has  similar problem? Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to get the value "Number 10" so you can store it off so you can use it in another it block to use it check another page (view)?

Comment: Yes, but how to store it? Is it possible without creating an array?  
The best way  would be create one variable for one value

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use values from DOM in cypress test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730959/how-to-use-values-from-dom-in-cypress-test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you may want to use .its

`cy.get('selector').its(propertyName).should('contain', 'string')`

its needs to be chained off a previous command like get.  You can also use this in a function as per Cypress's example

Cypress shows an example for DOM elements

> Get the length property of a DOM element

```
cy
  .get('ul li')       // this yields us a jquery object
  .its('length')      // calls 'length' property returning that value
  .should('be.gt', 2) // ensure the length is greater than 2
})
```

> You can access functions to then drill into their own properties
>   instead of invoking them.

```
// Your app code
// a basic Factory constructor
const Factory = (arg) => {
  // ...
}

Factory.create = (arg) => {
  return new Factory(arg)
}

// assign it to the window
window.Factory = Factory

cy
  .window()                 // yields window object
  .its('Factory')           // yields Factory function
  .invoke('create', 'arg')  // now invoke properties on itv
```

> You can drill into nested properties by using dot notation.

```
const user = {
  contacts: {
    work: {
      name: 'Kamil'
    }
  }
}

cy.wrap(user).its('contacts.work.name').should('eq', 'Kamil') // true
```

For the full list of examples and rules check out Cypress.io documents https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/its.html#Syntax